# connecting to Mongodb inside a docker with mongodb compass GUI

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, localhost

I have a mongodb database running on the default port 27017 in a docker container.

Is there a way to connect to the database with the mongodb compass GUI running natively on my ubuntu OS?

Comment: Why don't you `docker inspect your_container_name` to get its IP address and then try to set up a connection with Compass. Did you try that?

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the container?

Comment: @tgogos Thank you for your kind response, that worked.

Answer (score 40):

`docker run -p 27018:27017` and then connect from Compass on your host with port 27018. I don't see a reason to expose all ports.

Comment: To avoid confusion,
exact command is(on Mac OS): 
`docker run --name <custom-name> -p 27018:27017 -d mongo:<tag-name>`
this command does
download docker image and deploy/start container

Comment: `27107:27107` should work too. Why change the host port?

Comment: Worked for me perfectly. I ran `docker run --name <custom-name> -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:<tag-name>` (on Mac OS).

I was then able to use `mongodb://localhost:27017/` as my Connection String in MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 19):

Replace `localhost` with your IP address in the connection string, eg, my IP address is 10.1.2.123 then I have `mongodb://10.1.2.123:27017?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false`.

Saw this  here: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host

Comment: This was key for me.

Comment: There should be no reason to do this. As other answers say, localhost will work fine

Answer (score 16):

With docker-compose you just have to expose the port `27017`. When You hit "Connect" in the GUI it will auto-detect this connection.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongo-database:
    container_name: mongo-database
    image: mongo:4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Comment: after this change must access MongoDB using compase just by `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Answer (score 7):

Use docker inspect or docker desktop to inspect and find the exposing port

```
docker inspect your_container_name
```

and find this section

```
       "Ports": {
            "27017/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "27012"
                }
            ]
        },
```

and then connect using this url string

```
mongodb://localhost:27012/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false
```

Do not pass in replica set name if you are using one otherwise connection will fail. This is if you have deployed a replica set instead of turning your standalone to a replica set.

Leave a comment if you don't know how to deploy a replica set and I can leave a docker-compose file to set up and deploy replica set.

Comment: But why did you map host 27012 to container port 27017 in the first place?

Comment: I tried the other answers, but based on the replies of the first question this worked for me. I'm using Windows 11, and using docker inspect <image> worked  for me. Connected using 0.0.0.0:27107

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can run

Steps:

1. Pull/Restart the docker container mongodb
2. Enter the bash shell

   ```
   docker exec -it mongodb bash
   ```
3. Now open the mongodb compass community and with same default connection just click connect and the docker container's mongodb will be connected to compass community.

My terminal running docker:
[image: My terminal running docker]

Mongodb Compass:
[image: Mongodb Compass]

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Do I need to first open the bash shell before connecting to mongo DB using compass?  Can't we do it without it?

Answer (score 5):

In my case if I did as [Massimiliano_Marcon](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/compass-cant-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker/12351/3?u=tiago_peres)

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

then was able to connect just fine with the string `mongodb://localhost:27017`

[image]

But then, if I tried to connect to a container that started with Testcontainers, only worked if I've used `mongodb://localhost:27017?directConnection=true`

[image]

Comment: `directConnection=true` is the only thing that worked for me also.

Answer (score 2):

I could connect the compass on windows to a docker using these tags at the end:

`mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbname?authSource=dbname&readPreference=primary&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false`

Answer (score 1):

Run command `sudo docker ps`
it will show docker containers you have where you can find the port number of **mongodb**
the run the command `sudo mongodb-compass`
it will open the mongodb compass

If you are connecting locally so general hostname is : **localhost**
and then just put the port number and click on **connect**.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having trouble connecting to my local MongoDB using Compass, but discovered it was an SSL problem. By default, Compass sets SSL to "System CA". However, if you try that with your dockerized Mongo, your Mongo logs will show you this error:

```
Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support. Ending connection from 172.17.0.1:45902 (connection id: 12)
end connection 172.17.0.1:45902 (0 connections now open)
```

Therefore, to connect, I had to click "Fill in connection fields individually" then set the SSL field to "None". For reference, I ran Mongo using this:
`docker run -p 27017:27017 --name some-mongo mongo:4.0`. No authentication necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just open compass and inside connect add the credentials if you have used envs like

```
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
```

and hit connect.No addition settings required.
Or you can use mongo-express which a web based UI tool for monodb.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

Run the docker container using:

`docker run -d --name mongo-db -v ~/mongo/data:/data/db -p 27017:27017 mongo`

-v is for mapping the local volume to the docker writable space. This will keep the data even when the container is destroyed.

MongoDB connection string Compass GUI:

`mongodb://localhost:27017`

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the other answers beyond saying how to persist the database, which wasn't part of the question

Comment: It looks like a complete answer to me. I came across similar issues while connecting to Mongo and then with persistence. This covers everything that one could possibly need to get going.

Comment: Question was only asking about connection, not persistence

Answer (score 0):

Use the --net=host option for Docker container shares its network namespace with the host machine.

> docker run -it --net=host -v mongo_volume:/data/db --name mongo_example4 -d mongo

So now we can connect the mongodb with compass using **mongodb://localhost:27017**

Other hand to connect, simply get the docker container IPAddress using the docker inspect command and use that ip address instead of localhost

**mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017**

Answer (score -1):

Run your mongo container with 'publish-all-ports' option (`docker run -P`).  Then you should be able to inspect the port exposed to the host via `docker ps -a` and connect to it from Compass (just use  your Hostname: `localhost` and Port: `<exposed port>`).

Comment: There should only be one port exposed.