# Connecting to Mongo Docker container from Mongo Compass on local machine?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, ip, mongodb-compass

I have the following `docker compose` file that I use to spin up a `mongo` docker container which works as intended.

However, I cannot seem to connect to the container from `compass` on my local machine.

I executed `docker inspect` on my mongo container and got its `IP` and tried to connect using compass, but it didn't work - connection timed out.

Is it the IP of my docker network or the IP of the mongo container I need?

**docker compose file:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  pokerStats:
    image: pokerStats
    container_name: pokerStats
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493688/connecting-to-mongodb-inside-a-docker-with-mongodb-compass-gui).

I had to change my `docker-compose` file to expose port 27018 on my local:

```
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
```

And my connection details on `Compass` to be:

[image]

Comment: can I ask why it's 27018? not 27017

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping port 27017 from your host machine to port 27017 on the container. So the following connection string should work `mongodb://localhost:27017`

Comment: This just connects to a local Mongodb?